# Is it possible to change the contact field on all cases from a lookup to a non-linking text field?

Tags: lightning, contact, delete, object, lookup-field

We are cleaning up old contacts and running into the issue of being blocked by linked helpdesk cases.

We no longer use Salesforce as a helpdesk but would like to keep record of cases in case we need to reference back.

Is there a way to change the contact ID object on all case pages to simply being a text field containing just the contact name that does not link back to the contact, allowing us to delete those old contacts without issue?

Comment: Out of the box - contact reference (via a lookup) is not a required field. You can blank it out or change it to a dummy contact. The contact ID can be copied to a non-lookup field if you want to retain it for history.

Comment: Copying to a non-lookup field and then removing all in the actual field would be a perfect solution. We have several thousand to process. Is there an easy way to automate this?

Comment: For one-time task, an Apex snippet run via developer console or (if you prefer no-code) a [Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/build-flows-with-flow-builder) would be our suggestions for automation.

Comment: You might need to create a Batchable class and invoke from anon apex if this would not work synchronously due to data volumes...

Comment: To anyone looking back at this question for a solution for the automation:
I created a flow which is triggered any time a contact is updated to inactive 
On trigger, it checks for all cases with a matching Contact ID
Stepping through each one, the first and last name is copied to a custom read only field on the case page called "Original Contact"
Then the contact is changed to a dummy account called "Contact Deleted"
This essentially removes all cases from a contact when they are marked inactive while still preserving the information on cases.